# How to view or export WMS data in tabular format?

Tags: wms, attribute-table

Is there any way to export or view data from a WMS in tabular format?

The info tool brings up a table showing the attributes for the selected feature, but I want to view attributes for all features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no - that isn't what a WMS is designed for. You want to look at a WFS if you need the attributes for all the features in an area.